# Mobile Safari Push Notifications

Tags: mobile, safari, push-notification, mobile-safari

A few months back I saw that Safari 7 was allowing push notification and it seemed like a very useful tool except every example of it that i've seen is focused on desktop browsing, not mobile.

Do the Safari push notifications work on mobile and if not is there plans to release this to Safari mobile in the near future?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess it is just for OS X, at least for now. I received a mail from Apple broadcasting this: https://developer.apple.com/notifications/safari-push-notifications/.

I am also waiting for web-based push notification on iOS. But it seems Apple is pursuing a native-first strategy on iOS platform, giving native apps much more privilege than mobile web.

Comment: This still the case? anyone know if native local web notifications have been implemented yet? works so well on desktop, shame not to make it transferable

Comment: It seems it's still 'in development' as per Nov 2017 - https://webkit.org/status/#specification-service-workers

Answer (score 5):

**[Updated]** Web Push Notifications depend on "Service Workers" which are "Supported" in WebKit (Mobile Safari), but **the state of Push Notifications is unclear.** – *Kudos to [Chris Talman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1458158/chris-talman) for the update*

- https://webkit.org/status/#specification-service-workers
- https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker/

Comment: Service Workers are now marked as 'Supported'. The trouble is, neither the Push API nor the Notifications API are listed at all with any status. You'd think they'd at least be listed as 'Under Consideration'. I suspect it may be because the developers are reluctant to support Web APIs that are still in flux. Even so, there's practically no transparency on this process, which is a real shame.

Answer (score 3):

Since this was 2 years ago, I no longer think this is of service, but Apple has no plan to expand to mobile nor has any plan for push notifications on mobile. I have been on the Apple developer site and have found that there is no way for push notifications on IOS. However, Users using Google Chrome can use push notifications on Android using the Push API (https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/push-notifications-on-the-open-web?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Safari 16 in macOS 13 will support the Notifications API. Details are vague / possibly protected under non-disclosure agreement during the macOS beta.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/sending_web_push_notifications_in_safari_and_other_browsers

The Safari 16 release notes doesn't make particular mention to iOS/iPadOS 16 & Mobile Safari, however.

> ### Web API
>
> #### New Features
>
> - Added Web Push Notifications support on macOS.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safari-release-notes/safari-16-release-notes

Answer (score -1):

Right now there's no way to send push notifications to mobile Safari nor any plan to add it in the future.

However the latest versions of Chrome on Android started to support the push notifications through the Push API, so Apple might want to add push support to iOS to avoid being outdated by Android.